# Complete newbie CSS question about dropdown submenus

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a page with a navigation bar that has dropdown submenus. Unfortunately, something keeps going wrong: hovering over an option makes the submenu show up over the bar and list the submenu options horizontally.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Toy CSS</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
/* -------------------------MAIN-MENU----------------------- */
#topmenu ul {
    margin-left: 0; /* clears default margins */
    padding-left: 0; /* clears default padding */
    background-color: #036;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 100%; /* creates complete bar */
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#topmenu li {
    display: inline;
}


/* ----------------------MAIN-MENU-LINKS-------------------- */

#topmenu a {
    padding: 3px 10px;
}

#topmenu a:link, #topmenu a:visited {
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    background-color: #036;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-decoration: none; /* removes link underlining */
}

#topmenu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
}

/* --------------------------SUBMENU------------------------ */

#topmenu li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #69f;
}

#topmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#topmenu li:hover li {
    float: none;
}

#topmenu li:hover li a {
    background-color: #69f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #000;
}

#topmenu li li a:hover {
    background-color: #8db3ff;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.mainbox {
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 600px;
}
.mainbox ul li {
    width: 500px;
}
.mainbox {
    display: none;
}
</style>

</head>


<script>
$(function() {
    $('#topmenu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tabContent = this.hash;
        $(tabContent).show().siblings('.mainbox').hide()
    });
});
</script>



<body>

<!-----------–-–-–-–--------TOP-MENU-------------------------->
<div id="topmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#optiona">Option A</a>
    <ul>
    <li>A1</li>
    <li>A2</li>
    <li>A3</li>
    <li>A4</li>
    <li>A5</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#optionb">Option B</a>
    <ul>
    <li>B1</li>
    <li>B2</li>
    <li>B3</li>
    <li>B4</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#optionc">Option C</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-----------–-–-–-–---------OPTIONS-------------------------->
<div id="optiona" class="mainbox">
<h2>Option A</h2>
<p>You've selected Option A. Here is a list.</p>

    <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div id="optionb" class="mainbox">
<h2>Option B</h2>

<p>You've selected Option B. Here is a list.</p>
    <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div id="optionc" class="mainbox">

<h2>Option C</h2>
<p>You've selected Option C. Here is a list.</p>
    <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What is supposed to happen instead?

Comment: The submenu should drop down below the hovered-over option in the navigation bar. See this example: http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#topmenu ul li {
    display: list-item;;
}

#topmenu ul li ul {
    margin-top:25px !important;
}
```

Should do the trick...

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/dA5ta/)

Comment: Thanks, but two questions: (1) what does "display: list-item;;" do, and (2) why do the submenu options have such an incredible width?

Comment: ahh - I see you've double specified the `li {display}` to solve the main problem.  you can remove `#topmenu li {display: inline;}` as it's now redundant :)

Comment: @Dave2 (1) `display:list-item;` does exactly the same as what @simon sugested with `display:block` I prefer to use the former. (2), because they are filling the width of the `<ul>` add in `width:Npx` to get the desired with you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just have one more question (I hope): why doesn't `margin-top:25px;` work the same way as `margin-top:25px !important;`? I thought the "important" was just a comment, but apparently it's a command?

Comment: @Alex -- yeah, 'list-item' is a good call.  I thought it was poorly supported by older browsers, but I've just checked on quirksmode.org and it's absolutely fine.  +1 for you :)

Comment: CSS works on a points scheme, elements with the highest points, get override the rest. adding `!important` forces it to have the highest points. Thats a very basic explanation of it.

Comment: Heres the points scheme explained really well: [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Thanks. One more big problem. The submenus aren't opening under their respective options. For example, the B submenu opens under A instead of opening under B. See: http://jsfiddle.net/dA5ta/12/

Comment: [Check it out now](http://jsfiddle.net/dA5ta/13/) I've given each of you menus ids then added `left:Npx` to shift the menu to the left

Comment: Huh, I thought dropdown menus were supposed to show up under their respective options automatically, without having to shift them around pixel-by-pixel.

Comment: In the original example you posted [http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-dropdown-menu/](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-dropdown-menu/) they do. If thats the same result you're trying to achieve, use the code they're using.

Answer (score 0):

that root of the problem is that

```
#topmenu li {
    display: inline;
}
```

is cascading, so that the submenu `<li/>`s are also inline.  you should correct it with something like

```
#topmenu li li {
    display: block;
}
```

and go from there :)

Comment: Thanks. But now I'm totally confused. I thought the "display: inline" was necessary in order to create a horizontal navigation bar. But the example I'm looking at (http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-dropdown-menu/) doesn't use inline anywhere!

Comment: they're using `float:left` which offers a similar result.